# How can I exclude specific column in the Include method in EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I've got a User model with a Password property. It's widely linked to other entities using its Id property. However, whenever I use something like `context.SomeModels.Include(m => m.User)`, I would get the User's Password property selected from the database.

This is quite dangerous, especially I've got some result caching. I wonder is it possible to kind of globally configure that I want to exclude the User's Password property when it is 'Include'd in Linq.

Comment: Nope. `Include` is *not* a replacement of `Select`. Use the later or move the password to another "entity" sharing the same table with `User` (a.k.a. *table splitting*) so you could optionally `Include` it only where needed. But  projection (`Select`) is the only way to guarantee you are returning only the fields you specify.

Comment: Hacky and i don't like that, but should work - add `[JsonIgnore]` to property https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I can't, because there indeed are scenarios for the User, such as changing password, where I do need the Password.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for the lights. I will think about which way to go, table splitting or projection. Table splitting requires changes to database models, meaning database schema as well, while projection involves changing all containing DTO definitions to use the 'safe' User DTO as the navigation property.